# How to keep backup or save latest WordPress build in Github

Tags: wordpress, github, backup

I am making a WordPress website and I might create new builds. How will I keep back up or save my latest builds, I would prefer to use and manage builds through github. Is there a particular way that I can do it in WordPress?

Comment: What do you mean by "Wordpress build"?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to install this plugin and create your WordPress backup and download it :

https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Answer (score 0):

I used [gitwatch](https://github.com/gitwatch/gitwatch) to automatically commit new code to a Github repository. This included new uploads and new plugins. Just follow the ReadMe and it works pretty well.

[This is an example of a website where I used this technique.](https://github.com/rockboroschool/website)

**Words of Caution**

- Use .gitignore to exclude your wp-config.php file so that database credentials etc are not stored to github.
- Be careful not to dump your database to the wordpress directly (which
  would automatically commit it to Github).
- Be careful of plugins
  that write sensitive stuff to a file that might get committed.
- I am aware of [Kerchoff's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle), or not attempting security through
  obscurity, but I am not stupid about the risks of automatically
  publishing all of your configuration publicly. The site above is not
  a high profile complex site (and I generally like to think I know
  what I'm doing). DO NOT do this at home if your website is handling
  sensitive information or could be at risk of anything more targeted
  than a general Wordpress security flaw dragnet on Google.
- One partial solution to these concerns would be to just make the Git repository private.
- Finally if you are dealing with European data you need to comply with GDPR
  which means you need to be ready to scrub a file from Git history
  using something like [BFG](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/)

Answer (score 0):

You are addressing two different things. For backups, there are WordPress backup plugins that you can use like updraft (here's the link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/updraftplus/). But when it comes to development workflow then GitHub is the right platform. If you want to know how to work in a live environment and how to push and pull the latest changes from local to live or vice versa
(to keep track) then this guide will help you. https://www.cloudways.com/blog/wordpress-github/